# deployment not taking changes

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, wildfly

some minutos ago my Eclipse/WildFly deployment stopped to work correctly, my deployment is not taking the changes in the JAVA CODE,

i was using this Interceptor just to see which method i was accessing in the by the url

```
    public void intercept(InterceptorStack stack, ControllerMethod method,
            Object instance) throws InterceptionException {

        //Pega URI Acessada
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
//      System.out.println(method);
//      System.out.println(method.getMethod());
            stack.next(method,instance);



    }
}
```

if you see, it has the // so must stop printing, but even after the Deploy, it still show the accessed method in the console, WHY? if i make changes in the .jsp pages it change normally, but the JAVA not,

```
23:06:53,985 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "TestProject.war" with deployment "TestProject.war"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess class file is not building in the eclipse,so you are deploying the old version.I guess you mistakenly `click the 'Build Automatically' option in the "Project" menu`.Wheneevr this option is unchecked,your class file will not be updated automatically.So please check the issue